# String max length validation is not working in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation

In one of my applications I have an endpoint from which I want to validate its input parameters.

One of the parameters that this method receives is a string and I have tried to set the maximum length of it but it does not work. When I make the call to the endpoint with a string of more than 100 characters I can do it without problem and it should not be allowed

The problem is that I need to carry out this validation with the minimum possible changes since this method is called from other applications that I do not manage and it would be expensive to carry out any type of modification: Incorporate the attributes to a bean

```
@SecuredApi(securityLevels = {SecuredApiLevel.COMPANY, SecuredApiLevel.USER})
@GetMapping("/example")
public ResponseEntity<SearchRestDTO> search(
    **@Valid @Size(max=100)** @RequestParam(value = "query") @ApiParam(required = true, value = "The query that is searched") String query,
    return new ResponseEntity<>(searchService.search(query)), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: You have to use @Validated on class level. Without it, validations won't be picked.

Answer (score 0):

On the class level, use `@Validated` and then validations annotated with `@Valid` should work fine.

Here is the sample code which is tested -

```
@Validated
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/example")
    public ResponseEntity<String> search(
        @Valid @Size(max=5) @RequestParam(value = "query") String query) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("String Length is valid.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Moreover, @Valid is not required until you have complete object to validate.

Following dependencies is needed -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi @Akash, thanks for your anwser. I have tested using "validated" and the validation continues not working

Comment: @vcima Can you please paste your POM here if possible?

Comment: I have updated my answer with working code (tweaked your example code a little bit). Please check. You also need to add error handler and proper error messages for production usage.